# How can I get data from JSON Array

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am using mvc5. Please help me to get data from JSON array.
This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = ObjRepo.GetEmployees(1);
    ObjHybrid.data = data;
    //  return View(ObjHybrid);
    return Json(new {data=ObjHybrid},behavior:JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Right now I am getting data as

```
{"data":{"data":[{"Emp_Id":101,"EmpName":"Hussain","Email":"Hussain@gmail.com","Psw":null,"Cnt_Id":0,"Cnt_Name":"India"}]
```

But I need as

```
"Data:[{...........}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing an anonymous object with a `data` property and it's value is your `ObjHybrid` object.

Looks like you want `ObjHybrid` object as the response json data. In that case, do not use the anonymous object. Just Pass the  `ObjHybrid` object as the first parameter(*data*) of the `Json` method

```
return Json(ObjHybrid,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Convert it in your ajax, like this:

```
 var ResponseData= JSON.Signfy(data);
```